# Selenium from Jupyter Notebook not sending keys

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook

From a Jupyter Notebook running Python 3, I'm running the following code to try and insert the text "a search term" into the Google search box with Selenium [1]:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# get the path of ChromeDriverServer 
chrome_driver_path = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver 2"

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)

# navigate to the application home page
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# get the search textbox
search_field = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

# enter search keyword and submit
search_field.send_keys("a search term")
```

However, when I run the code, I just get a new browser with the Google homepage open *but the text isn't inserted into the search bar*. What am I missing here?

[1] Make sure to have the right webdriver installed -- I initially installed the 32-bit version but then had to install the 64-bit version, since the "2".

Answer (score 0):

The reason was because my 64-bit Chrome Web driver was outdated; the most recent version as of this writing is 2.37 and can be downloaded here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/

Code now works.